# Is there anything more that I can do with Java 'Build Path Problem'?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse

I tried making a web site page with jsp and tomcat.

I made a Dynamic web project and then made a jsp file on it.

Then I typed 'hello jsp'

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>`enter code here`
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    hello JSP~!

</body>
</html>
```

like this and ctrl f11.

Hello JSP is exactly printed on the chorme but there is a error mark on Dynamic web project file.

The problem is JAVA BUILD PROBLEM and the description is '
Archive for required library: '/Volumes/T7/KGitbank/JSP (6월)/apache-tomcat-9.0.63/lib/._tomcat-i18n-ko.jar' in project 'JSP01' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file  JSP01'.
I did lots of things to solve it like but it still doesn't work..

I put tomcat in my external hard drive.. Is that a problem...? What can I do else?

Comment: Have you confirmed that file exists at that location (`ls /Volumes/T7/KGitbank/JSP (6월)/apache-tomcat-9.0.63/lib/`) and is indeed valid (`jar -tf /Volumes/T7/KGitbank/JSP (6월)/apache-tomcat-9.0.63/lib/._tomcat-i18n-ko.jar`)?

Comment: Files starting '._' are macOS extended attributes files, this seems to be confusing something. These files are only used by macOS if the file system is **not** a macOS file system (HFS+ or APFS) - so put the jar somewhere that uses a proper macOS file system.

Comment: @greg-449 You mean I have to put tomcat file in MacOs not in exteranl drive??

Comment: External drives can be formatted using a macOS file system (but other operating systems may not be able to read them)

Comment: But I am using MacOS.. Then it should have been read... But it still doesn't work..

Comment: Fine, so you need to make sure your external drive is using a proper macOS file system. What does Finder "Get Info" say for the external drive in the "Format" field.

Comment: Yes I solve it ! But there is one thing more..
when I Ctrl Fll there is a 'the selection cannot be run on any server' sentence. So I went to properties and change the server form 'None' to 'Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost' but it still doesn't work!!

Comment: What is the selection at that time? Was the Answer to basically the same question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72531602/is-there-some-more-solutions-to-solve-the-java-build-problems not work?

Comment: Yes but I just solved the problem.. Thank you so much..
The problem was my MacOs couldn't read my external drive...so i  put tomcat in Mac Os. Then the selection problem was Java version : ( But still doesn't know the meaning of 'selection' haha

Comment: What does Eclipse think you were trying to run?

Comment: @nitind tomcat maybe

Comment: Don't guess. What was selected in the IDE?

Comment: @nitind Eclipse!